# MSDTC has canceled the Distributed transaction

Tags: c#, wcf, msdtc

i have a DTC error that occurs on production server randamly.i have WCF service hosted in IIS7 in windows 2008R2 server and another WCF services hosted as a windows service hosted on the same server and Database server sql 2008 hosted in another clusterd server windows 2003.
the transaction propagetes from wcf service hosted in IIS to another 4 wcf services hosted as windows services in order like this:

client ->WCF service (IIS)->WCF service 1 (winService)->WCF service 2 (winService)->WCF service 3 (winService)->WCF service 4 (winService)

Binding between all services is net.tcp binding.
My issue is i get this error randamly and i dont know why or how to trouble shot it the error is:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Account Entry was not saved ...  The Microsoft Distributed Transaction
>   Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction. (Fault
>   Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.Exception:
>   Account Entry was not saved ...  The Microsoft Distributed Transaction
>   Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction. ---->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The Microsoft Distributed
>   Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed
>   transaction.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) ...).

i have checked the DTC congfiguration and  i checked allow inbound & out bound checkboxes and choosing No Authentication requierd but the error still appears randamly and sometimes we have to restart the server to solve this issue.
Can u plz help me to understand it and how can i deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: You write ".. the transaction propogates from.." can you clarify what you mean by transaction ? I don't think you mean that you've got a transaction scope spanning several different services.. or do you ?

Comment: I think he does - this is a valid question therefore and should not be closed.

Comment: yes transaction scope spanning several services